# Importing XML into Access via XSL with parent note repeating with child nodes

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I'm trying to import an attribute centric XML file into Access using an XSL transform. What needs to happen is something along the lines of converting this (disguised to keep from violating company policy):

```
<PLANETARY Protocol="Solar 1">
  <COLONIES>
        <COLONYDATA site="10001" planet="Mars">
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="RadiationDanger" value="Low" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="ApplicantColonists" value="11" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="AcceptedColonists" value="3" />
        </COLONYDATA>
        <COLONYDATA site="10002" planet="Mars">
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="RadiationDanger" value="Low" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="ApplicantColonists" value="7" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="AcceptedColonists" value="1" />
        </COLONYDATA>
    </COLONIES>
  </PLANETARY>
```

Into this:

```
<Protocol>
    <COLONIES>
        <COLONYDATA>
            <protocol>10002</protocol>
            <site>10001</site>
            <planet>Mars</planet>
            <RadiationDanger>Low</RadiationDanger>
            <ApplicantColonists>11</ApplicantColonists>
            <AcceptedColonists>3</AcceptedColonists>
        </COLONYDATA>
        <COLONYDATA>
            <protocol>10002</protocol>
            <site>10002</site>
            <planet>Mars</planet>
            <RadiationDanger>Low</RadiationDanger>
            <ApplicantColonists>7</ApplicantColonists>
            <AcceptedColonists>1</AcceptedColonists>
        </COLONYDATA>
    </COLONIES>
</Protocol>
```

Ultimately what I really need is for the table in Access to look like this, converting the XML into what I have above may or may not be the optimal route, but it does work:

```
protocol    site    planet  RadiationDanger ApplicantColonists  AcceptedColonists
Solar1      10001   Mars    Low             11                  3
Solar1      10002   Mars    Low             7                   1
```

The sainted Lingamurthy gave me the following code, which does everything except get the parent node to repeat along with the child nodes (mainly because I didn't know I needed it at the time):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*" >
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/PLANETARY">
    <Protocol>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Protocol"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </Protocol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RESOURCEDATA">
    <xsl:element name="{@resource}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If possible, I'd like to understand how this is working. I have to admit that at this point XSLT doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. It's quite a bit more abstract than VBA, which I've become very comfortable with. But I'd be happy with any suggestion that gets it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Your obfuscation will keep us safe from rivals in the solar system -- well done!  +1 for good question otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure, but I guess you want the `PLANETARY/@Protocol` in every `COLONYDATA` and not the `site`'s value. And how do you want the another output(table like)? Do you want to use HTML code to display on your browser or do you want it to be plain text?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="Protocol" select="/PLANETARY/@Protocol"/>

<xsl:template match="@*" >
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/PLANETARY">
    <Protocol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </Protocol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RESOURCEDATA">
    <xsl:element name="{@resource}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="COLONYDATA">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Protocol>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Protocol"/>
        </Protocol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, this produces exactly what I need. Thanks again, @Lingamurthy CS! I'm now using this, http://xslttest.appspot.com/ to selectively break the code piece by peice to see if I can actually learn to do this myself.